# How to parse META-INF/maven/plugin.xml files using the Maven API-s

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I need to parse a Maven plugin's `META-INF/maven/plugin.xml` file using the Maven API-s. I assume I need a class from the [maven-plugin-tools](https://github.com/apache/maven-plugin-tools), but I can't seem to find the right one.

Could somebody please show me a working example, or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why do you need to parse the plugin.xml ? This is done by Maven during the life cycle...usually no need to do this manually ?

Comment: This is not a usual case, @khmarbaise. We need it for some metadata generation and we'd like to use the proper Maven API-s.

Comment: Can you give more information what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: I need to get the plugin's prefix.

Comment: @khmarbaise: We working on this pull request on Github: https://github.com/strongbox/strongbox/pull/479. The current implementation uses SAX to parse the `META-INF/maven/plugin.xml`, but I believe we should be using some class from the Maven API for it to be more efficient. As you are one of the Maven developers, perhaps you'll know...?

Comment: @khmarbaise: I mean, whatever writes this XML file (https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.2/maven-plugin-api/plugin.html), must be able to parse it back. Could you please illustrate the best way to do it?